# How do I display the result of App.js with a html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase

I'm a noob so the question may be dumb.
But I have a react project and I want to access with a bouton on a html file, is it possible, for the moment with this code, when I click on the bouton "connexion" I have only the code that display on my screen but not login page.
How to resolve it ? Thank you.

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="navbar.js"></script>
    <script src="recherche.js"></script>
    <script src="chat-app/src/App.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
</head>

    <header>
        <!-- à changer : quand on se connecte changer connexion par nom prenom et go sur la page profil-->
          <!--<div window.onload="script.js/initApp()" id=navigation>-->
              <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img alt="logo revenir à la page d'accueil" src="logo.png" height="71" width="71"></a>
                <a href="whoweare.html" >Qui sommes-Nous?</a>
                <a href="access.html">Un mot sur l'accessibilité</a>
                <a href="recherche_lieu.html">Je veux visiter</a>
                <a href="chat-app/src/App.js" class="nav-connexion">Connexion</a> <!--si connecter <a href="users.html" class="nav-connexion">nom+prenom</a> -->
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="navbar.js/navbar()">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
    </header>
  <body>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1327226581/fr/photo/toile-aquarelle-verte-abstraite-pour-le-texte-le-logo-fond-aquarelle-dessin%C3%A9-%C3%A0-la-main.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=0ZPYDrPODO_WwtDDblB_Y23LqvEYcVmEIrSJ1vDF6Y4=" alt="Chateau de Versaille">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Un mot sur l'accéssibilité</h1>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Le handicap, qu'il soit visible ou invisible, fait partie de l'expérience humaine. Nous vivons dans un monde diversifié où chaque individu a sa propre expérience unique de la vie. Cependant, les personnes en situation de handicap peuvent souvent se heurter à des obstacles qui limitent leur participation à la société.</p>
      <p>Une société inclusive est celle qui valorise tous ses membres et donne à chacun la possibilité de participer pleinement. Elle reconnaît que chaque personne a quelque chose de précieux à apporter et s'efforce de supprimer les obstacles qui pourraient empêcher certains de participer pleinement.</p>
      <p>La participation à la citoyenneté est un aspect essentiel de l'inclusion. Cela signifie donner à chacun la possibilité de participer à la vie de la communauté, que ce soit par le travail, l'éducation, le vote, le bénévolat ou d'autres formes d'engagement civique. Cela signifie également garantir que chacun a accès aux ressources et aux services dont il a besoin pour vivre une vie épanouissante.</p>
      <p>L'accessibilité joue un rôle crucial dans la réalisation de cette vision. En veillant à ce que les environnements, les produits, les technologies et les services soient accessibles à tous, nous pouvons aider à créer une société où chacun a la possibilité de participer et de contribuer.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

App.js

```
import { auth } from "./config";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import ChatRoom from "./components/ChatRoom";
import "./App.css";

import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";

const App = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [currentRoom, setCurrentRoom] = useState("General");

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <NavBar
        user={user}
        currentRoom={currentRoom}
        setCurrentRoom={setCurrentRoom}
      />
      <div className="content">
        {user ? <ChatRoom currentRoom={currentRoom} /> : <Outlet />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Login.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../config';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log(userCredential);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='login'>Login Page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <input
        className='login form-style'
          type="email"
          placeholder="Your Email"
          required
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
        className='login form-style'
          type="password"
          placeholder="Your Password"
          required
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" className='login button-connect'>Login</button>
      </form>
      <p className='login'>Need to Signup? <Link to="/signup">Create Account</Link></p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Protected.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Protected = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  return (
    token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
  )
}

export default Protected
```

I want to go to the App.js and the login page display.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `<a href="chat-app/src/App.js" class="nav-connexion">Connexion</a>` simply will not work. For the actual "Connexion" page to load via an HTML link you will need to create an HTML file for that specific page first and then link that HTML page with your **app.js** using `<script src="chat-app/src/App.js"></script>` which should go right above `</body>` (it is required for it to be within `<body>`, but it is also preferred for it to be at the bottom most part of the `<body>` to make sure it affects all elements within `<body>`.).